# Style For Bindings?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I have some text boxes in a user control:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBox>
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Street, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBox>
```

Is there a way in XAML to do something like a style for my bindings so that I don't have to write for each text box the `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` but only the `Path=` part?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't a way to do this via XAML or a Style. The best you can hope for is to build a custom control that changes the default behavior. Something like:

```
public class MyTextBox : TextBox {
    static MyTextBox() {
        TextProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyTextBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata() { DefaultUpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged });
    }
}
```

Then you'd need to use `MyTextBox` in place of the `TextBox`.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I was already on that solution but I was hoping that I was missing something regarding XAML. Unfortunately not.

Answer (score 5):

I too got real annoyed at writing some crazy long binding phrase **EVERY** time I wanted to bind to a property, so I did that for over a year before I stumbled across [this post.](http://www.hardcodet.net/2008/04/wpf-custom-binding-class)

It basically subclasses `MarkupExtension` (which is what a `Binding` class is)to an abstract class called `BindingDecoratorBase` provides all of the properties that the Binding class provides. So from there you could do something like this:

```
public class SimpleBinding : BindingDecoratorBase
{
  public SimpleBinding(string path) : this()
  {
    Path = new System.Windows.PropertyPath(path);
  }
  public SimpleBinding()
  {
    TargetNullValue = string.Empty;
    UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
  }
}
```

And then all you have to do in your xaml is include your namespace at the top and then
to bind to a control do something like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{m:SimpleBinding Name}"></TextBox>
<TextBox Text="{m:SimpleBinding Street}"></TextBox>
```

This makes it easier than trying to subclass every single control that you want to write less in the binding phrase.

Comment: This is a much better approach than subclassing.  Here you can apply the technique to any binding on any controls.  Have you ever encountered any shortfalls with this technique?

Comment: Not really, quite the contrary. It has given me more control, e.g.  I used to use a NotConverter to bind a property to IsEnabled, but with this approach I allowed some C# syntax and let the MarkupExtension negate for me. So my MarkupExtension allows this syntax `"{m:SimpleBinding !IsEnabled}"`.