# How to automatically set ValidatesOnExceptions, ValidatesOnDataErrors and NotifyOnValidationError in all TextBoxes?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, setter

Currently, I'm creating textboxes and specifying ValidatesOnExceptions=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True every time I create a binding:

```
<TextBox Width="150" Text="{Binding Expander1Name, ElementName=Window, 
         Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
         ValidatesOnExceptions=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, 
         NotifyOnValidationError=True}" Background="#FFF5EECC"></TextBox>
```

I would like to set ValidatesOnExceptions=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True with a global XAML setter.

Can anyone here give a definitive answer whether it is possible to do, if not - why, if yes - how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible in the way you describe, since these properties are present on the `Binding` instances within the `DependencyObject`s rather than being exposed as properties on the `DependencyObject`s themselves. It is not possible to create a `Style` that targets `Binding`s.

That said, there are a couple of ways you could work around this:

1. Define your own class that extends `Binding` and sets whatever defaults you want. You would then use that class everywhere you've currently used `Binding`.
2. Define an attached behavior that finds all `Binding`s within the object to which it is attached and sets the defaults you want.

The first option would be preferable to me, since the second could have unforeseen consequences (what if there's a binding where you *don't* want it to take on the defaults?). The second option would also be much slower, since it would need to dynamically search through all dependency properties of the item to which it is attached.

Answer (score 1):

I asked almost the same question some time before maybe you can have a look also there:

[Style For Bindings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743158/style-for-bindings)

Comment: yeah, I saw the answers. The problem is that I like doing the design in Blend, and there's no way to change the default binding class there, and if I have to change Binding to ProperBinding every time, I as well might copy paste the property assignations

Comment: @Arsen Then I think you can't avoid it. By the way I don't like copy paste. I prefer to have one place to change something that is used more than once. But of course it is your choice on what fits you best.

Comment: don't like cpp myself). Thanks for the suggestion though. Lets hope they get it right in the next XAML version